# The best way to compress a video on a macbook

Tags: macos, video, compression, quicktime, after-effects

I know it seems to be a simple question, but I found there are not many clear answers from google.

I have a 10 second with low resolution/PPI for a website. It was sized about 3MB.  Is it possible to make it below 1MB? What tool should I use?

Computer is a Macbook Pro. I have some software like After Effect, Quick Time Player, but neither seems to be able to compress it.

Comment: Use ffmpeg. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28803/how-can-i-reduce-a-videos-size-with-ffmpeg https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-mac

Answer (score 0):

After Effects, Adobe Media Encoder, QuickTime Pro or ffmpeg as suggested by @Jameson. After Effects should be able to compress your video. It depends on your codec and its settings. e.g. H264 with a datarate of 200kbits/s should create a small low resolution video. You will have to play with the settings of your codec to get the right balance between size and quality loss.